# Can this be automated Black screen during software installation?

Tags: python

During certain software installation, windows display screen can go black or flickers black screen but installation succeeds; to check black screen during installation came up with the following, does this look correct or can this be improved?

```
import time
import pyautogui

def capture_screenshots(duration, interval):
    start_time = time.time()
    end_time = start_time + duration

    while time.time() < end_time:
        screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
        if is_black_screen(screenshot):
            screenshot.save(f"black_screen_{time.time()}.png")

        time.sleep(interval)

def is_black_screen(image):
    black_threshold = 10  # Number of black pixels threshold
    black_pixels = sum(1 for pixel in image.getdata() if pixel == (0, 0, 0))
    return black_pixels >= black_threshold

capture_screenshots(duration=120, interval=5)
```

Comment: The frame buffer probably does not get painted black, so you won't catch it like this.  It's more likely that the backlight is being turned off or the desktop is being switched to administrative mode, and neither one of those can be detected.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The reason is to automate graphic driver installation and capture issues like black screen during installation.

Comment: Impossible.  The black screen during driver initialization is caused by shutting off the video signal, NOT by painting the screen black.  It's an electrical thing, not a memory thing.  The frame buffer won't change, so it can't be detected.